# save method is not able to save the object using Hibernate + Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My Dao layer has a save method as:

```
public void savePerson(PersonBean personBean) {
    Session currentSession;

    try {
        currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        currentSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println("Opened Session");
    }

    currentSession.merge(personBean);
    System.out.println("Data Saved");
}
```

And the applicationContext.xml is defined as :

```
<bean id="oracleDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:{mylocalInstance}" />
    <property name="username">
        <value>PersonDataBase</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>person</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingLocations" value="PersonBean.hbm.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="testTransactional" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!--<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="testTransactional"/>-->

<bean id="personDao" class="com.dao.PersonDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="personService" class="com.service.PersonServiceImpl">
    <property name="personDao" ref="personDao"/>
</bean>
```

It is able to create the tables but the data is not saved, as I have to show the sql, this is the sql generated when trying to save:

```
INFO: Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@68be8808] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Opened Session
Hibernate: 
select
    max(PERSON_ID) 
from
    PERSON_BEAN
Data Saved
```

Why is select query being generated when I am trying to save it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit your transaction as well.

Try this:

```
public void savePerson(PersonBean personBean) {
    Session currentSession;

    try {
        currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        currentSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
        System.out.println("Opened Session");
    }

    currentSession.beginTransaction(); 
    currentSession.merge(personBean);
    currentSession.getTransaction().commit()
    System.out.println("Data Saved");
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also set `hibernate.connection.autocommit` property to true in Hibernate configuration if you don't want to handle transactions manually.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
```

Comment: Yes it worked, but doesn't hibernate handles that internally, or do we need to add `@Transactional` to do it.

Comment: Automatic transaction management is not enabled by default. But you can enable it. See [this] answer for more details.

Comment: Can you please provide the link for [this] word, I think you missed it.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Oh! my bad. I've updated that in my answer only. Just change `hibernate.connection.autocommit` property to `true` and hibernate configuration and you won't have to handle transactions manually then.

Answer (score 0):

Try **currentSession.save(personBean)**
and if you properly configured the Spring then you don't need to

**beginTransaction()** Spring will handle the transaction .

public void savePerson(PersonBean personBean) {
    Session currentSession;

```
try {
    currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); 

} catch (HibernateException e) {
    currentSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
    System.out.println("Opened Session");
}

currentSession.beginTransaction(); 
currentSession.save(personBean);
currentSession.getTransaction().commit()
System.out.println("Data Saved");
```

}

Comment: I tried save, saveandupdate, persist, nothing works until I begin and commit the transaction.

Comment: Yes you need to commit the transaction to persist data to data base. But if you able to configure hibernate with spring then string will begin , commit your transaction. You just need to put @ Transactional on the method. 
https://github.com/keaz/mysite/blob/feature/website/src/main/java/com/kzone/service/MemberServiceImpl.java